# PHP echo Script not working

Tags: php, echo

So I have background music on a site and I am trying to make the music pause if there is a video on the page, but when I try to `echo` a script, my embedded video disappears. I am a bit lost on this one:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4PzOqCpxyEU';
preg_match(
    '/[\\?\\&]v=([^\\?\\&]+)/',
    $url,
    $matches
);
$id = $matches[1];

$width = '640';
$height = '385';
echo '<object width="' . $width . '" height="' . $height . '"><param name="movie"      value="http://www.youtube.com/v/' . $id . '&amp;hl=en_US&amp;fs=1?rel=0"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/' . $id . '&amp;hl=en_US&amp;fs=1?rel=0" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="' . $width . '" height="' . $height . '"></embed></object>';
if($id = $matches[1]){ 
           echo '<script>jQuery(function(){ app.events.trigger('audioplayer.pause') });    </script>'; } 
 ?>
```

Comment: You are closing your `echo` operand after `trigger('`.

Comment: try `echo '<script>jQuery(function(){ app.events.trigger("audioplayer.pause") });</script>'; }`

Answer (score 2):

escape the `'`

```
 echo '<script>jQuery(function(){ app.events.trigger(\'audioplayer.pause\') });</script>';
```

Also use here `==` instead of `=`

```
if($id == $matches[1])
```